# Underline some text and center the subscript

Tags: html, css

[image]

Please see attached image. How would I achieve an underline effect like this using CSS?

Comment: Not an answer, but why would you want to use this? I'm sure there must be other ways to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: It’s not a subscript. And you should show your best effort so far, instead of expecting others to solve your (vaguely specified) problem for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is exactly what you are looking for:

**HTML:**

```
<span class="underlined">example text<hr/>#</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.underlined {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    text-align:center;
}
.underlined hr {
    border:none;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    margin:0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7GQ73/).

The span is displayed as `inline-block` element, so it'll allow line-breaking elements such as `<hr>` inside the `span`. Using that, you can simply put a `<hr>` between the text itself and the subscript, and you'll have the desired result. The `vertical-align` is required to make the text itself fit in the regular flow of the text, pushing the subscript to below the text.

Be warned though, this will disrupt the flow of the text. I don't know what you wanted to use this for, but I think there is probably another way to get the result you want, without having to use this.

Answer (score 0):

This would take some fine tuning, but something like this might work:

```
<p>Your <span class="toUnderline">test <span class="subscript">3</span> some</span> more text.</p>|
<style>
   .subscript {
    line-height:-15px;
    letter-spacing:-5px;
    text-decoration:none;    
    }
     .toUnderline{
    text-decoration:underline;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: You may even want to add the span.subscript in dynamically with jquery, and insert it into the exact middle of each span.toUnderline to keep things consitant.

Comment: I would use Joeytje50ès answer

Answer (score 0):

I would use absolute positioning and percents to provide you the flexibility to place this in a class and reuse without tweaking.  [**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/asapmmeehan/84mVx/)

Structure your HTML like so:

```
<p>This is a simple statment with some <span class="underline">underlined text<span>3</span></span>and a number under it. But it s a bit longer to mix it up.</p>
<p>This is a simple statment with some <span class="underline">underlined text<span>3</span></span>and a number under it. But it s a bit longer to mix it up. But it s a bit longer to mix it up.But it s a bit longer to mix it up.But it s a bit longer to mix it up.But it s a bit longer to mix it up.But it s a bit longer to mix it up.</p>
```

Structure your CSS like so:

```
p {
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:2.2em;
}
.underline {
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.number {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:.5em;
    left:50%;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Another CSS method would be :

```
p {
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:2.2em;
}
p span {
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
p span span {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:.5em;
    left:50%;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```